# Angular throwing error when running the following code

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="number" ng-model="limit"/>
<button ng-click="runNames()" />


<div style="height:150px;width:150px" class="boxed" ng-repeat="name in names">
    {{name|uppercase}}
</div>
```

```
mainModule.controller('helloWorldController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.runNames = function () {
        $scope.names = [];
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.limit; i++) {
            $scope.names.push("pratik");
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: What error? What were you expecting it to do? This isn't how programmers should ask questions about code. Learning how to ask questions should be debugging 101. http://blog.codeunion.io/2014/09/03/teaching-novices-how-to-debug-code/

Answer (score 1):

If you really [want to have duplicated items](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) in array, make sure you tell Angular to index them by `$index` so that Angular could distinguish individual items:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names track by $index">
    {{name|uppercase}}
</div>
```

Comment: the error says it all:
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: name in names, Duplicate key: string:pratik